# Modificar datos con axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, laravel-8

Usando `vue js` y una api en `laravel 8`, estoy intentando modificar los datos de una tabla usando el método `post` de `axios`.

Modal para modificar los valores:

```
<div>
  <b-modal id="modal-1" v-model="showModal"  title="Editar">
    <input type="text" id="client" name="client" :value="this.client" >
    <button type="submit" @click="handleOk(client)">Enviar</button>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Métodos de `vue js`:

```
methods: {
    openModal(id){
      this.showModal = true;
      this.client = this.info.find(com => com.id === id).client;
    },
    handleOk(clientt){
      axios
          .post('/orders/edit', {client: clientt})
          this.showModal = false;

    }
  }
```

La ruta de la API:

```
Route::post('/orders/edit', [OrderController::class, 'update']);
```

El controlador de la API:

```
public function update(UpdateOrderRequest $request, Order $order)
{
    $order->client = $request->client;
    $order->save();

    return header('http://localhost:8080/orders');
}
```

Al clicar el botón `Enviar` del modal, este mismo se cierra pero los datos no se guardan en la base de datos. Que problema puede haber?

Answer (score 0):

podrias arreglar tu metodo de vue volviendolo async y con un console.log() ver lo que te devuelve.

```
async handleOk(clientt) {
    try {
//aqui deberia ser un await axios.post(`/orders/edit/{id}`
        const res = await axios.post("/orders/edit", { client: clientt });
        if (res.status == 200) {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.showModal = false;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
},
```

de esta forma se esperara a que devuelva un res.status y el modal pase a `false` y tambien en tu controlador puedes hacer un trycatch para devolver algun error

```
public function update(UpdateOrderRequest $request, Order $order)
{
    try {
        $order->client = $request->client;
        $order->save();
        return header('http://localhost:8080/orders');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

por lo que veo tu error esta en el controlador, ya que la funcion update pide una inyección Order, pero no se la estas dando en la ruta de esta manera

```
Route::post('/orders/edit/{order}', [OrderController::class, 'update']);
```

por lo que no guarda nada, lo que espera la ruta : `/orders/edit/3` donde 3 seria el id del `order` a editar. igual recomiendo usar el verbo `put` si es solamente para modificar datos, ya que `post` es para crear (a mi parecer).